# Swift: create an infinite tree using tableview

Tags: ios, swift, tree, tableview

I'm making a tree, which has a root node and infinite levels.

What I want to achieve is:

- Use a tableview to display the nodes of the current level, starting from the root node. Each table cell is a node. (I'm able to hard code it to display the nodes of a specific level.)
- When tapping a table cell, display the node's next level children in a tableview.
- This goes on and on, until you click a node which doesn't have any children. Then it just does nothing.

I know tapping a cell can trigger *performSegueWithIdentifier*, which goes to the next scene. But, since the tree has infinite levels, I guess merely going to another scene doesn't work. Instead, there must be a way to repeat the current scene (tableview to display current level nodes) with information about which level it is.

Please advise the best way to handle this situation. Thank you.

The sample tree structure is here: (

```
class Node {
  var id:Int;
  var parent:Int?;
  init(id:Int, parent:Int?) {
    self.id = id;
    self.parent = parent;
  }
}

var allNodes = [
  Node(id:1, parent: nil),
  Node(id:2, parent: 1),
  Node(id:3, parent: 1),
  Node(id:4, parent: 2),
  Node(id:5, parent: 2),
  Node(id:6, parent: 3)
];
```

Comment: I am pretty sure you won't be able to represent *infinite* levels on any current or future computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply update your data source (allNodes) to be the child nodes in the tableViewDelegate method:`tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` and then remove the other rows from the tableView and call tableView.reloadData() which means your rows will now simply be the child nodes of the previously selected cell and keep going until you hit the leaves where you could then check if it has children, in the didSelectRow method, and if it has no children then do nothing.

That's how I would do it...